# How to toggle input class depending on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, input

I have a very basic contact form which has 3 inputs that I need to adjust the styling of depending on whether or not they have focus.

With the JavaScript I currently have, I get the desired result only upon a click event but not when the input has focus in general.  For example, I would like to toggle the designated "scale" class if they were to also tab through the inputs as opposed to just tapping or clicking inside or outside of them.  For that I think toggling the class based on focus would be a much better solution but had no luck using .focus() or .is(":focus").

Also, tapping outside of the form input on mobile does not remove the "scale" class like clicking does on a desktop browser.  Not sure how to handle that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nolder/fuxtky01/1/)

```js
var $input = $('input, textarea');

// Remove focus class if user clicks outside it
$(window).on('click touch', function() {
  if ( $input.parent().hasClass('scale') ) {
    $input.parent().removeClass('scale');
  }
});

// Scale form container on click
$input.on('click touch', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().addClass('scale');
  $input.not($(this)).parent().removeClass('scale');
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(230,232,235,1);
}

/* Section container */
#form-section {
 padding: 5%;
}

/* Form */
form {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 400px;
}

/* Form - hover */
form > div:hover > div {
 opacity: 0.65;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
}

/* Form field containers */
form > div > div {
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,10,20,0.10), 0 6px 10px rgba(0,10,20,0.06);
 margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
 position: relative;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
  width: 85%;
}

/* Form field containers - hover */
form > div > div:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
}

/* Form field scale class*/
form > div > div.scale {
 box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0,10,20,0.12), 0 10px 20px rgba(0,10,20,0.1);
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale3d(1.05,1.05,1);
 transition: 0.3s ease;
}

/* Form label */
label {
 background-color: rgba(242,245,248,1);
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 color: rgba(165,175,185,1);
 display: block;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 500;
 height: 30px;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 line-height: 30px;
 width: 100%;
}

/* Inputs */
input,
textarea {
 border: none;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
 color: rgba(115,125,135,1);
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 width: 100%;
}

/* Message input */
textarea {
 min-height: 100px;
 resize: vertical;
}

/* Submit button */
input[type="submit"] {
 background-color: mix(white, rgba(87,37,18,1), 20%);
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: white;
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 width: 120px;
}

/* Submit button - hover */
input[type="submit"]:hover {
 background-color: rgba(87,37,18,1);
 box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,10,20,0.25), 0 8px 12px rgba(0,10,20,0.12);
 cursor: pointer;
 transform: translate3d(0,-2px,0);
 transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="form-section">

  <!-- CONTACT FORM -->
  <form>
    <div>
      <!-- NAME -->
      <div class="input_scale">
        <label for="name">NAME</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
      </div>
      <!-- EMAIL -->
      <div class="input_scale">
        <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email">
      </div>
      <!-- MESSAGE -->
      <div class="input_scale">
        <label for="message">MESSAGE</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="user_message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SUBMIT -->
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  
</section>
```

Comment: how's this? https://jsfiddle.net/fuxtky01/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `click touch`, in your first function use `blur`

> The [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) event is fired when an element has lost focus.

```
$input.on('blur', function() {
    if ( $input.parent().hasClass('scale') ) {
        $input.parent().removeClass('scale');
    }
});
```

In the second, use `focus`

> The [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) event is fired when an element has received focus.

```
$input.on('focus', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().addClass('scale');
    $input.not($(this)).parent().removeClass('scale');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery .focus() event. try this:

```
 $input.focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('scale');
    $input.not($(this)).parent().removeClass('scale');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $input = $('input, textarea');

// Remove focus class if user clicks outside it
    $(window).on('focusout', function() {
        if ( $input.parent().hasClass('scale') ) {
            $input.parent().removeClass('scale');
        }
    });

    // Scale form container on click
    $input.on('focus', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().addClass('scale');
        $input.not($(this)).parent().removeClass('scale');
    });
```